# Wordpress theme uses a deleted image

Tags: wordpress, replace, media

I am using a wordpress theme for my website and when installing the theme I made sure to avoid imporing the media files of the theme. The problem is that the theme keeps using a featured image that doesn't exist. I have tried to replace the image with my own and when inspecting the page I can see that I am using mine but what us displayed is always the theme default image.

Is there anyway to solve this, because I have cleaned all my website and tried again but no result.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted to clear your cache (browser and/or plugin)? Also a screenshot of the inspection may assist the community in debugging. Please upload a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1.can you check the template file if that is a part of the header or footer
could be that the image is hard-coded

2.if you have cache enabled try deleting the cache

3.Sometimes the demo content in themes is linked with images from the developers website demo site
check the network tab if the image is fetched from a different website.